# wp_users, wp_usermeta table join query not work for me

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select

wp_users, wp_usermeta table join query not work for me

```
SELECT distinct(a.ID) FROM wp_users as a 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as b ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE a.id < 1000 AND b.meta_key != 'user_name' AND (b.meta_key = 'first_name' AND b.meta_value = '')
```

I want to find data where user_id(a.id) is less than 1000 and there is no user_name(wp_usermeta table) field in meta_key and first_name(wp_usermeta table) in meta_key is blank.

However, this query does not check for user_name data.
What is wrong with my query?

I tried

```
SELECT distinct(a.ID)
FROM wp_users as a 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as b ON a.id = b.user_id 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as c on a.id = c.user_id 
WHERE a.id < 1000 AND c.meta_key != 'user_name' AND (b.meta_key = 'first_name' AND b.meta_value = '')
```

not worked. and i tried LIKE statement and NOT IN () .. etc

I think I've used everything I can..

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by `a.ID` is a good scenario over distinct. The `SUM(expression)` added up the expression value (either 0 false, or 1 true). By using `HAVING` as a post grouping criteria allows this to be your filter.

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(meta_key = 'user_name') as un, SUM(meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value = '') as fn
FROM wp_users as a 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as b ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE a.id < 1000
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING un = 0 and fn = 1
```

Comment: This is awesome.
That's a way I've never thought of. Thank you.

However, if  I do this, un and fn look the same in select query 
I hope to see only the ID value.

Is there a way?

Comment: You can move the expressions of `un` and `fn` into the having clause afaik.